# Making sprite move towards mouse

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am making bullets using p5.play.js but for some reason when this code runs the bullet just stays still and does not move anywhere... Thanks for your help in advance!

```js
function mousePressed() {
  var bullet = createSprite(player.position.x, player.position.y);
  
  bullet.addImage(bulletImg);
  bullet.life = 120;
  bullet.scale = screenSize/3;
  
  var dx = mouseX - bullet.postion.x;
  var dy = mouseY - bullet.postion.y;
  var angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);

  bullets.add(bullet);
  bullet.setSpeed(7, angle);
 
}
```

Comment: There's no code here that updates the position of the bullet.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. What exactly does `setSpeed()` do? What do you do with those values? When do you actually move the bullets?